# Angular y Bootstrap table con ngClass

Tags: angular, bootstrap

Generé código para que una fila entera se coloree al clickear un botón. Funciona correctamente cuando uso sólo la clase table ( de bootstrap) la cuál usa un fondo blanco, o gris claro si le agrego striped . Sin embargo cuando quiero usar la clase table-dark que pinta de colores oscuros la tabla, la fila elegida no se colorea presumiblemente por que este color esté actuando por encima de lo que indica el CSS de mi ngClass.  Este es el código mío.

CSS

```
.fila-coloreada{
background-color: red !important ;
}
```

VISTA

```
<table class="table table-dark table-striped " *ngIf="hayRegistros(); else sinarticulos">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Codigo</th>
      <th scope="col">Descripcion</th>
      <th scope="col">Precio</th>
      <th scope="col">Borrar</th>
      <th scope="col">Seleccionar</th>
      <th scope="col">Cambiar Lugar</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let art of articulos; , let i = index;" [ngClass]="{ 'fila-coloreada': art.colorearFila == true }">
      <th scope="row">{{art.codigo}}</th>
      <td>{{art.descripcion}}</td>
      <td>{{art.precio}}</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="borrar(art.codigo)">Borrar?</button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="seleccionar(art)">Seleccionar</button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="colorear(this)" (click)="corroborarSeleccion(i)">Cambiar de posición</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<ng-template #sinarticulos>
  <p>No hay articulos.</p>
</ng-template>
```

Intenté dos soluciones que no funcionaron: una colocar el !important en el CSS y otra aumentar mucho la especificidad     del selector:

```
.table.table-dark.table-striped tbody tr.fila-coloreada{
background-color: red !important ;
}
```

También revisé el archivo original de la librería de Bootstrap  (Bootstrap.css) pero al ser mi nivel básico no logro entenderlo correctamente. Por si sirve lo adjunto:

```
.table-dark {
  --bs-table-color: #fff;
  --bs-table-bg: #212529;
  --bs-table-border-color: #373b3e;
  --bs-table-striped-bg: #2c3034;
  --bs-table-striped-color: #fff;
  --bs-table-active-bg: #373b3e;
  --bs-table-active-color: #fff;
  --bs-table-hover-bg: #323539;
  --bs-table-hover-color: #fff;
  color: var(--bs-table-color);
  border-color: var(--bs-table-border-color);
}
```

Comment: Y usando `[ngStyle]`?